# How to use an empty variable in Grafana query

Tags: monitoring, grafana

I have grafana on sage and made a mage v2 query that works like a charm

```
group="platform_client" env="prod" event='all-requests-result'
serviceName='myServiceName' result="error" 
$customFilter | timechart limit=0 count by serviceName
```

But I don't like how it went with `$customFilter` variable. I made it "custom" type with values `1=1, | dedup ip`. `1=1` is a crutch for "do not apply additional filters". Is there a more elegant way to do it?